# Request for member in something not a structure or union

Tags: objective-c

Here's some background on my program: `[self.channels`] is an array of `Channel` objects. Each `Channel` object has a synthesized string called `channelId`.

**Compiles**

```
Channel *channel = [self.channels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *channelId = channel.channelId;
```

**Does not compile**

```
NSString *channelId = [self.channels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].channelId;
// Request for member 'channelId' in something not a structure or union
```

Why couldn't I chain my commands to get the `channelId` property? The two versions of my code look the same...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Objective C: Request for member XXX in something not a structure or union](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534105/objective-c-request-for-member-xxx-in-something-not-a-structure-or-union) from the **Related** sidebar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first version the compiler knows what kind of object you are working with since it is using a Channel* variable to reference the data member. In your second version the compiler only knows that an NSObject may be returned but has no immediate knowledge that the returned object will be of a certain class.  You can change this by casting the returned value:

`NSString *channelId = ((Channel*)[self.channels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).channelId;`